# how enable multiple file upload in webview android 4.4 and up

Tags: android, android-webview, android-file

I'm using html `input` tag. I'm trying to upload up to 5 files. Code is working for single file upload. 
How can I enable multiple file upload in webview android 4.4 and up?

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
```

This only multiple allows selecting files but it doesn't work

```
ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 3;
final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 32;
ValueCallback uploadMessage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("https://contactde.com/");
    webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            if (newProgress >= 100) {
                pd.cancel();
            } else {
                pd.setMessage("Loading " + newProgress + "%");
                pd.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }


        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        //For Android 4.1+ only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            }
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {

            Log.d("LogTag", message);
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }

    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.loadUrl(uriUrl.toString());


}


private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        Log.e("Url", url);
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://wa.me/")) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(myIntent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    // Forward results to EasyPermissions
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
        if (uploadMessage == null) return;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data));
        }
        uploadMessage = null;
    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        Uri result = data == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : data.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly for image files, but doesn't work for mixed files types such as png, mp4, mp3, pdf, doc etc. Can you please suggest something about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured out

Link [Here](http://michael-huang.logdown.com/posts/1660565-open-file-chooser-in-webview)

and just add

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for sharing the link as it was really helpful :+1:

Answer (score 1):

For selecting multiple image from gallery

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
```

**An Ultimate Solution for multiple image upload with camera option also for Android Lollipop to Android 10, SDK 30.**

```
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 1;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessages;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
```

**Add this to OnCreate of MainActivity**

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                openImageChooser();
            }

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mUploadMessages = filePathCallback;
                openImageChooser();
                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }

private void openImageChooser() {
    try {
        File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FolderName");
        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

        });
```

**onActivityResult**

```
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == mUploadMessage && null == mUploadMessages) {
                return;
            }

            if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                handleUploadMessage(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            } else if (mUploadMessages != null) {
                handleUploadMessages(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }





    }

    private void handleUploadMessage(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null

                result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

        // code for all versions except of Lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                        result = null;
                    } else {
                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }

        } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop






    private void handleUploadMessages(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                results = null;
            } else {
                if (data != null) {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            results[i] = item.getUri();
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                } else {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI};
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessages = null;
    }
```